# Toggle HTML elements using Angular and sockets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I try to create an administration panel with which I could set the displays of users in real time with sockets .

I use it for **Angular** , **Angular Material** , **NodeJS** and **Socket.io**

I have a back-end controller with a checkbox . When I click on , the value is then saved to emit NodeJS

**Controller Back-End**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('myController', ['$scope','mySocket', function( $scope, socket ){

    $scope.activated = true;

    $scope.toggle = function(){ 
        socket.emit('activated',{ value: $scope.activated });
    }
});
```

**Template Back-end**

For html I use angular material like this

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="activated" 
             aria-label="Checkbox 1" 
             ng-change="toggle()">
             {{ activated }}
</md-checkbox>
```

**Controller Front-end**

The front-end controller is the same as the previous one except that the event listening socket.

```
socket.on('activated', function( data ){

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // here is my problem
        // the ng-if don't react when $scope.activated is changed
        $scope.activated = data.value; 
    });
});
```

**Html front-end**

```
<div my-service ng-if="activated"></div>
```

The purpose of all this as you will understand this is to enable / disable features (in my case a directive).

My question is why in my case, the Directive does not reappear when it is passed once false. I mean, if I do not change the value and I keep only the console.log , everything works ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The probleme comes from ng-if, it's not a good method to do this. Have you got another idea ? With ng-show, it's ok but i would like to really remove the element from the DOM

Comment: try using `$apply()` ... angular needs to be notified of scope changes that occur outside of angular core in order to run digests. Also seems to be a mismatch between `activated` and `chatActivated`

Comment: mismatch corrected, I will study $apply()

Comment: ok, i put a $apply and now the script don't break, the value is updated but the ng-if don't react and stay false...

Comment: `value` should be an object so it will always be truthy, try `$scope.activated = value.value;` or don't pass object in the `emit`

Comment: It seems to be ng-if problem, with ng-show it's ok, but i want to remove the element, not hide

Comment: use an object instead of a primitive in the scope . It could be a child scope problem. `ng-if` for example creates a child scope so if there is another one higher up it would break the inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope problem. Since you have a directive `myService` on that element where you use ng-if. ng-if creates an isolated scope which causes problems. Or your attribute directive can create isolated scopes and the problem is the same.
Use ng-show and your problem will be solved most probably.

Comment: btw `myService` should be `my-service` isn't it?

Comment: you're probably right and i'm studying this post : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4046

Comment: Just accept my answer if it was the solution. Thanks.